# Regular expression match in JavaScript matches too much

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this expression:

```
"g{field1}={field2}a".match(/{([^\{\}]+)\}/g)
```

What I need is to get "field1" and "field2", but it returns an array with "{field1}" and "{field2}".

Comment: Since JS regexes don't have lookbehinds, just remove the first and last character of the strings

Comment: What do you mean, Doorknob?

Comment: Checking to see if there's a character before a certain match without matching the character is not supported in JS regexes. ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) Instead, just take each string and remove the first and last character.

Comment: @Doorknob That isin't true, `exec` will support multiple capturing groups per match.

Comment: @plalx Technically the braces would still be captured, in a different group :P Yes, I didn't think of that. That is a good idea! (+1 to your answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exec` which can return multiple capturing groups per matches.

```
var re = /{([^\{\}]+)\}/g,
    matches = [],
    input = "g{field1}={field2}a",
    match;

while (match = re.exec(input)) matches.push(match[1]);

console.log(matches);
```

You can also re-write your regex (here it depends what the input string can be):

```
var matches = "g{field1}={field2}a".match(/{([^}]+)}={([^}]+)}/).slice(1);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Didn't know I could use match several times on the same string. That's just very elegant.

Comment: @ArnaudWeil `exec` will make the regex keep track of the index of the last match as it's `lastIndex` property. However make sure that you are only using `exec` as demonstrated with a *global* flag or you will have an infinite loop ;)

Comment: Downvote, really? Would be nice to know why so I can correct any incorrect statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an array without curly braces, you can use array map method:

```
"g{field1}={field2}a".match(/{([^\{\}]+)\}/g).map(function(i){return i.slice(1,-1)})
```

Comment: That's what Doorknob meant, and is the solution. I'm disapointed JS regexps don't do this, but it's a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead

`"g{field1}={field2}a".match(/[^\{\}]+(?=\})/g)`

this will match any character that is not `{` or `}` if the matched set of characters is followed by a `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
"g{field1}={field2}a".match(/([^g=a\{\}]+)/g)
```

returns

```
["field1", "field2"]
```

Comment: Err... except it won't work for any other input!!! I could also use ["field1", "field2"] hardcoded in that case...

Comment: True, too fast with this answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
'g{field1}={field2}a'.split(/[{}]/).filter(function(a,i){return i%2;});
```

provided the string always contains matching "{}" pairs. There is also:

```
'g{field1}={field2}a'.split(/^[^{]*\{|\}[^{]*\{|\}[^{]*$/g).slice(1,-1);
```

both of which will work on any number of {…} pairs (0 to n).